# Bremermann's limit vs Planck frequency

Tags: frequency, physical-constants, absolute-units

Bremermann's limit, as maximum possible computation power or CPU total computing frequency, is known to be on the order $10^{50}~\text{Hz}/\text{kg}$.
Why max computation frequency for unit mass can exceed Plank frequency, which is on the order of $10^{43} ~\text{Hz}$ and how it is related to it?

Comment: It's not Hz, it's bits per second.

Comment: Anyway why do you assume the computer is 1kg? Logically it should be 1 Planck mass and then its speed is less than the Planck frequency.

Comment: It's the same. Bits are unit-less quantity, and $1/s \equiv 1 Hz$. i.e. whatever number of non-dimentional things per second is Hz by definition

Comment: When you spell it out as "bits per second", it makes it obvious that it doesn't have to be one thing happening at 10^50 Hz. It could be 10^50 bits being processed once per second. Same way we say that an object spinning at 60 rpm spins at 1Hz and not 6.28 Hz, even though radians are dimensionless.

Comment: Or 1-bit at 10^50 Hz

Comment: Anyway lets concentrate on question, so you say that one should take Bremenman limit and multiply by Plank mass instead ? Can you expand on it with your answer then ?

Comment: And 60 rpm is just 1 Hz, because 1 spin per 1 second. Here is 10^50 bits per second processed analogically

Comment: 60 rpm is 6.28 radians per second, and radians are a unit-less quantity, so it's just 6.28 per second, right? And 1/s is 1Hz by definition so 6.28 per second is 6.28 Hz

Comment: @user253751 Yes, $6.28 Hz\,rad$ or $1 Hz\,spin$. Just because it's unit-less, it doesn't mean they are equal, nor that they can't exist at their own right.

Comment: In your first comment *you* said that bits per second are equivalent to Hz because bits are unitless.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113832/discussion-between-agnius-vasiliauskas-and-user253751).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's bits per second. It's not a frequency. It could be 1 bit being processed $10^{50}$ times per second, which would be faster than the Planck frequency, but it could also be $10^{50}$ bits being processed once per second each, which wouldn't.

You're also comparing things with different units. It's like saying that the Schwarzschild constant (mass of a black hole compared to its radius) is $1.34663531 × 10^{27} kg / m$, but the observable universe has a mass of $1.5×10^{53} kg$, so why isn't the observable universe a black hole? Well, the observable universe has a radius of more than 1 metre. Or, the speed limit is only 50 mph, so how can you drive from from New York to Philadelphia (94.5 miles)? Well, it takes more than one hour.

If you *were* going to choose an arbitrary amount of mass to put into the equation, there's no reason it would have to be 1kg. A more "natural" amount of mass would be something like the Planck mass or the electron mass. (very different amounts of mass, by the way). If the speed limit *did* somehow dictate how far you could travel, it would be more logical to multiply it by the Planck time, than by 1 hour - and by that reasoning your car couldn't even drive a millimetre, which shows how that reasoning is completely wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I have not expressed my question in a good way. The core thing which I was interested in was,- Can a Bremermann's limit be calculated using only Plank units or at least approximated by it ?

Thanks to @user253751, I can now understand that. Usually maximum possible bit-rate is achieved by equating quanta energy to $mc^2$ :

$$mc^2 = hf $$,

then maximum bit-rate possible **per unit mass** is :

$$R_b = \frac fm = \frac {c^2}{h}$$

which is $1.3 \times 10^{\,50} ~\text{bps}/\text{kg}$, here "bps" means bits-per-second. Now, technically bit-rate has dimensions of $\text{Hz/kg}$, so one can approximate maximum bit-rate using *Plank frequency* and *Plank mass* :

$$ R_b = \frac{f_{_P}}{m_{_P}} $$

Using these we get $R_b$ also on the order $10^{50}$ bps/kg ! So conclusion is that bit-rate maximum limit can be quite accurately modeled using Plank units only.